# Inconvertible types Cannot cast

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-fragments

I am trying to implement maps and I am getting error of Inconvertible types; cannot cast `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` to `com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment`

I have seen some resources but nothing works for me

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements         OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap mMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}
```

> Inconvertible types; cannot cast 'android.support.v4.app.Fragment' to
>   'com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment'

Comment: What version of the Maps SDK are you using?

Comment: I am using api 23

Comment: No, I mean the version of `play-services-maps`

Comment: 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'

Comment: Add `activity_maps` layout with question .

Answer (score 4):

As per the [Google Play services Android release notes for `play-services-maps:17.0.0`](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases#june_17_2019):

> **Warning**: This release is a MAJOR version update and breaking change.
>
> - Update your app to use Jetpack (AndroidX); follow the instructions in [Migrating to AndroidX](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate).

Maps `17.0.0` has switched to [AndroidX](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx). That means that `SupportMapFragment` now extends [`androidx.fragment.app.Fragment`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment.html), not the Support Library equivalent. You need to either switch back to `16.1.0` or migrate your app to AndroidX.

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
```

with:

```
MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
```