# cannot cast 'android.support.v4.app.Fragment' to 'com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment'

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio, supportmapfragment

I created one new project with google maps activity and i installed google play services. I added the permissions of internet,fine location and coarse location.
I copied the URL which is mentioned in google_maps_api.xml and i generated API key.API key used in google_maps_api.xml and in manifest meta file.
Now i'm getting issue regarding supportMapFragment.

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap mMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
}}
```

[If i did Migrating app to AndroidX,then the errors are coming.Please click on this link to see errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8sVDy.png)

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

implementation 'androidx.core:core:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-ui:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
```

}

How can i overcome this issue.Please help me.

Comment: Migrating your app to AndroidX resolves this, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56963327/inconvertible-types-cannot-cast

Comment: i did that also.that issue is gone but some new issues are araised. that are 1)Cannot  resolve oncreate android oncreate(android.os.bundle). 2)Cannot resolve method 'setContentView(int)' 3)Cannot resolve symbol 'FragmentActivity' 4)Cannot resolve method 'getSupportFragmentManager()'

Comment: What are the version of `compileSdkVersion` and `buildToolsVersion` your app gradle? @Priyanka

Comment: compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.googlemaps1"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

Comment: Please send gradle dependencies? @Priyanka

Comment: i updated gradle dependencies in my code.Please check once.

Answer (score 0):

Migrate to AndroidX and then replace

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
```

with

```
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity;
```

Comment: I followed your answer.It showing "Application Installation failed" error.                           
Installation failed with message 'cmd package install-create -r -t -S 2026368' returns error 'Unknown failure: Can't find service: package'.
It is possible that this issue is resolved by uninstalling an existing version of the apk if it is present, and then re-installing.

WARNING: Uninstalling will remove the application data!

Do you want to uninstall the existing application?

Comment: because you don't fully migrate to androidx , and below line's to build.grade in app folder :                                                                                      
    implementation 'androidx.core:core:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-ui:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0'                                                  
     implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'

Comment: i added above mentioned lines and did sync.Again same error is getting

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use **androidX** you have to Migration from Android Support Libraries to Jetpack (AndroidX) Libraries.

- Upgrade com.android.tools.build:gradle to v3.2.1 or later.
- Upgrade compileSdkVersion to 28 or later.
- Update your app to use Jetpack (AndroidX); [Migrating to
  AndroidX](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate).

This is a video from [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c2GXtbmgA7Y)

Comment: Ok,Thank you..How can i implement google maps without any error in 3.4 version.I'm getting too many errors and i'm not understanding why these errors are come

Comment: Watch this video to see your problem is fixed or not  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PVlN_dZhAfw @Priyanka

Comment: Check your steps with official structure https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/start   @Priyanka

Comment: Thank you.I followed the official structure.